# How to get the year metadata of AVAsset URL in Swift?

Tags: swift

I tried the below method on an AVAsset URL and all I am getting is nil. Is there anything wrong in my code?

```
func getYear(musicName: String) -> Date? {
        let url = FileManager.customFolderURL.appendingPathComponent(musicName)
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
        let metadataList = playerItem.asset.metadata
        var date: Date?

        for item in metadataList {
            switch item.commonKey {
            case .commonKeyCreationDate?:
                date = item.dateValue
            default: break
            }
        }
        
        return date
    }
```

Comment: Is `metadataList` empty? Maybe use the async method with `loadMetadata(for:completionHandler:)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
func getYear(musicName: String) -> Date? {
        let url = FileManager.customFolderURL.appendingPathComponent(musicName)
        var date: Date?
        let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
        let metaData = asset.metadata
        if let artist = metaData.first(where: {$0.commonKey == .commonKeyCreationDate}), let value = artist.dateValue {
            print(value)
            date = value
        }
        return date
    }
```

This Code will work if your file contains value for property `.commonKeyCreationData`. I didn't have appropriate file for testing. But it was returning value for property `.commonKeyArtist` and if we would just replace `artist.dateValue` to `artist.stringValue`.

Comment: Looks like they updated this API for iOS 16.0. The new API is a huge PITA to get data out of it.

Comment: probably Adrian, you're right